# Extract body element without a particular child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html2canvas

Is there a way to extract body element without a particular child element in it?

For example, if I have:

```
<body>
  <div id="id1" class="class1" />
  <div id="id2" class="class2" />
</body>
```

, what I need to be extracted is:

```
<body>
  <div id="id1" class="class1" />
</body>
```

Actually, I intend to use [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) library to make canvas element from a HTML code, but I don't want to include all body children in a canvas element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you retrieve a parent element then you also have to take all of its children too. A possible workaround in this case would be to select the `body`, clone it and then remove the unwanted child element, something like this:

```
var $bodyClone = $('body').clone();
$bodyClone.find('#id2').remove();
// use $bodyClone as needed here...
```

Comment: That's the solution I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').not("#id2").html(); 
or 
$('body').not(".class2").html();
```

and this is for multiple

```
$( "div" ).not( ".someclass, #someid,.class").html()
```

hope it will help

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't how the `not()` selector works.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `document.getElementById(id)` to get one element

or `getElementsByClassName(class)` and then filter the returned array

Using better ids or classes could help you to avoid filtering at all, simply give all your canvases one class and replace them all.